# Singleton Query Used In PL-SQL Condition (IF Statement)

Tags: oracle, plsql

I get the following error when trying to run my code:

```
BEGIN
IF((select count(*) from tablename where column = 'value') > 0) THEN
-- do stuff.
ELSE
-- do stuff.
END IF;
END;
```

Error:

```
ORA-06550: line 2, column 5:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" when expecting one of the following:

   ( - + case mod new not null <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable>
   continue avg count current exists max min prior sql stddev
   sum variance execute forall merge time timestamp interval
   date <a string literal with character set specification>
   <a number> <a single-quoted SQL string> pipe
   <an alternatively-quoted string literal with character set specification>
```

Obviously the error code makes no sense. I'm getting used to this when working with Oracle.

The `COUNT()` function exists in PL. What else could it be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lance Link is that you under cover? You can't have a query in an IF statement. First do the query as a select INTO a variable, then test the variable:

```
DECLARE
  v_count number;
BEGIN
  select count(*) 
  into v_count
  from tablename 
  where column = 'value';

  IF ( v_count > 0) THEN
    -- do stuff.
  ELSE
    -- do stuff.
  END IF;
END;
```

Give Mata my regards.

Comment: Gosh. PL is tedious. Thanks, man! Mata sends his best wishes.